# Hyper-V 2016 doesn't shut down guests on host restart / shutdown

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

I am running an Hyper-V host with Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

All guests are configured to be saved at host shutdown and automatically startet again at host startup. This worked for a long time, but now it stopped working.

It seems that the guests will get killed everytime I shutdown or restart my host.

In the EventLog I see an entry which is maybe related to this:

> Der Dienst Hyper-V-Verwaltung für virtuelle Computer konnte nach dem Empfang eines Preshutdown-Steuerelements nicht richtig heruntergefahren werden.

I'll translate it into english:

> The service hyper-v-management for virtual computers could not shutdown properly after recieving a preshutdown-crontrolelement.

I found an support entry at Microsoft which seems to handle the problem I got, but it applies only to Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012R2 and not to Windows Server 2016. I mean this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2896800/hyper-v-guest-os-does-not-shut-down-when-you-restart-the-host-computer

Latest Windows Updates are installed at the host.